# How to create a new dictionary from a json file (python)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I'm a begginer with Python and I am working on a project with webscraping. After my request, I receive a json file with a lot of data about footballers.
However, some data on this file is useless.
[image: the json file]

For this reason, I'm trying to create a dictionary with the information I will use to do some analysis.
To be specific , this is the new dict I want to create

```
gk_info = {'name' : [], 'country' : [], 'Minutes' : [], 'SuccPass' : [], 'TotalPass' : [], 'Claims' : [], 'PossessionLost':[],
                'punches':[], 'savesBox' : [], 'Saves' : [],  'SuccLongBall' : [], 'TotalLongBall' : [], 'Tocuhes' : []}
```

But now starts my problem, some players have all this data above, but when the Player for example: a Player which don't have any Punches. The json for the player don't have the entry Punches.

[image: Example: This player don't have the attribute 'punches']

At the moment, this is my code:

```
for player in players_all['players']:
try:
    if player['position'] == 'G':
            gk_info['Minutes'].append(jogador['statistics']['minutesPlayed'])
            gk_info['name'].append(jogador['player']['name'])
            gk_info['country'].append(jogador['player']['country']['name'])
            gk_info['SuccPass'].append(jogador['statistics']['accuratePass'])
            gk_info['TotalPass'].append(jogador['statistics']['totalPass'])
            gk_info['Claims'].append(jogador['statistics']['possessionLostCtrl'])
            gk_info['punches'].append(jogador['statistics']['punches'])
            gk_info['savesBox'].append(jogador['statistics']['savedShotsFromInsideTheBox'])
            gk_info['Saves'].append(jogador['statistics']['saves'])
            gk_info['SuccLongBall'].append(jogador['statistics']['accurateLongBalls'])
            gk_info['TotalLongBall'].append(jogador['statistics']['totalLongBalls'])
            gk_info['Touches'].append(jogador['statistics']['touches'])

except Exception as err:
    continue
```

My for loop break if a player doesn't have a one of those values (KeyError). It's possible to do like, when don't have the entry, the program put a 0 and continue with the append on a new dict?